# Displaying an image in QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I have created a Qt interface, add a Qlabel and set pixmap to an image.         imagelabel =

```
        new QLabel(centralwidget);
        imagelabel->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("imagelabel"));
        imagelabel->setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 371, 311));
        imagelabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/liqi/kinect.png")));
```

this is the code displayed in ui_mainwindow.h
when i preview it using the Qtdesigner, the image can be displayed. But when i run using codeblocks, everything like buttons etc is fine but the image does not appear. Do i need to add anything into the section below ?

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(Tqt_interface* tqt, QWidget *parent ) : 
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}
```

Comment: Could be a problem with your resource file maybe. Did you check that?

Comment: i did. 
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/liqi">
    <file>kinect.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>

Answer (score 5):

`":/liqi/kinect.png"` ':' means you are trying to open image that is included as resource. Make sure u have `.qrc` file and it is added in `.pro` project file. Like:

```
RESOURCES += res.qrc
```

Also make sure that image is in the `.qrc` file.

Comment: added but still not working, instead of the original image, there is this mini "page" picture.

Comment: what page picture? if there is nothing at ":/liqi/kinect.png" you shouldn't see any icon.