# Replace some text with images Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, symbols

I would like to make a custom text entry widget in Qt in which certain groups of characters are automatically replaced by little images.  For example, I might want every instance of "cow" to be automatically replaced by a little icon of a cow.

Any idea how to do that?

I'm working in python but solutions in C++ syntax are more than welcome :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674606/displaying-an-image-in-qlabel

Comment: don't except solutions. What did you try so far?

Comment: Kamil Klimek: I read the documentation and looked for examples. I know almost nothing about HTML so it never occurred to me to use that until just now reading Shf's post. Also, now that I see how to do it, I see that my google-fu was off the mark and I understand that it's because I was too specifically searching for how to put images in a QTextBrowser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QTextEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qtextedit.html) widget for that.

From documentation :

QTextEdit can display images, lists and tables. If the text is too large to view within the text edit's viewport, scroll bars will appear. The text edit can load both plain text and HTML files (a subset of HTML 3.2 and 4).

The appropriate HTML construction to insert an image is `<img src="path_to_image">`. Just replace the words that should be converted to an image with that construction. To do this automatically, you can connect the [`textChanged()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qtextedit.html#id-2b355b6d-5fdc-4f49-8a57-db1d94085ddc) signal to a slot in which you replace key words with the HTML construction.

Also, you may find [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/22495-How-to-display-image-on-QPlainTextEdit) usefull.

Comment: Nice. If you will please accept my edit I will accept this answer.

Comment: @kjoppy mods rejected suggested edit, but i've edited it anyway :)

Comment: Your edit doesn't show up right. Re-read it maybe.

Comment: @kjoppy yep, forgot to put <img> in tilda's

Comment: Also, why the heck did the mods reject the edit? That's odd.

Comment: @kjoppy 3 rejects with "This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.
"

Comment: Wow, so you actually can't edit for clarity. Didn't know that. Thanks.